# what is the difference between node* and *node?

Tags: c, pointers

In the below binary tree implementation in c++ what's the difference of using pointer node* and *node.I am weak with implementation of pointers.

```
struct node  
{ 
    int data; 
    struct node *left; 
    struct node *right; 
}; 

struct node* newNode(int data)
{ 

  struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 

  node->data = data; 

  node->left = NULL; 
  node->right = NULL; 
  return(node); 
} 


int main() 
{ 
  struct node *root = newNode(1);   
  root->left        = newNode(2); 
  root->right       = newNode(3);

  root->left->left  = newNode(4); 

  getchar(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: So what does this code demonstrate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... can you point to specific lines that you are asking about?  Otherwise, the best answer here is that `node *` is a pointer to a node structure (it's just an address), whereas `*node` dereferences the pointer and returns the structure at the assigned address.  But it would be helpful to clarify your question.

Comment: FWIW: in declarations, “type* variable” and “type *variable” are the same. I prefer the former for clarity/consistency, and differentiating it from “\*variable” in an expression.

Comment: Specifically you do not have `node *` anywhere. You have `struct node *`.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather bad practice to use the same names the data types and the object names.

```
struct structnode  
{ 
    int data; 
    struct structnode *left; 
    struct structnode *right; 
}; 

struct structnode* newNode(int data)
{ 

  struct structnode* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 

  node->data = data; 

  node->left = NULL; 
  node->right = NULL; 
  return(node); 
} 


int main() 
{ 
  struct structnode *root = newNode(1);   
  root->left        = newNode(2); 
  root->right       = newNode(3);

  root->left->left  = newNode(4); 

  getchar(); 
  return 0; 
 }
```

And now the confusion has vanished.